# Send out literal string from web api in C#

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-web-api2

I have a literal string generated by my bussiness logic that I need to send out on my web api via my controller.

The end part of my controller function looks like this, where the text variable is a literal string, thus containing "\\" to indicate a single backslash:

```
var text = _transformation.ToTextFormula(new Formula("", formula, parts));
return Ok(text);
```

The problem this creates is that when I then consume my api the duble backslashes are still there and not just the single one intended. Surely there must be a way to correct what is sent out?

If I inspect the "text" variable to look at the value in real format there is just a single slash before leaving the method.